# Send values to another scene in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a character select screen in Unity. But I don't know how I can tell the game scene what skin got picked in the character select scene.

I have tried using `DontDestroyOnLoad();` but didn't get it to work.

I need to send the value from a canvas in one scene to a player object in the next scene. I didn't get a player prefab to work because many of the values the player need only exists in the game scene.

I am not much experienced with Unity or C#, so I would appreciate if you give very detailed answers and explain to me what different things do and why.

Lastly, I am sorry if this question is hard to understand, as I said, I'm not that experienced. I am also not that good in English. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

You may use PlayerPrefs for it (as a variant instead of `DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject)`): https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html

Comment: thank you for helping me out. This was not exactly what made it work. When I put this code in it did not work. I got really confused because I thought this would work and I discovered that this whole time I was calling the wrong method on button press. However, this was a very simple and clean way to send it to the other scene, and I also understood how it works. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use design pattern **Singleton** to create an unique instance.

```
public class CharacterManager
{
   private static CharacterManager singleton;
   private Skin currentSkin;

   public static CharacterManager Singleton
   {
      get
      {
         if (singleton == null)
         {
            singleton = new CharacterManager();
         }

         return singleton;
      }
   }

   public void SelectSkin(Skin skin)
   {
       currentSkin = skin;
   }

   public Skin GetCurrentSkin()
   {
       return currentSkin;
   }
}
```

**Usage**:

Select skin in Scene1

```
CharacterManager.Singleton.SelectSkin(someSkin);
```

Get current skin in Scene2

```
character.skin = CharacterManager.Singleton.GetCurrentSkin();
```